# How can I make a Java cross-platform GUI application (Windows, Linux)? What tools should I use?

Tags: java, linux, windows, user-interface, cross-platform

I'm new to Java GUI programming and I want to make a Java GUI application which can run both in Windows and Linux with the same code (the same executable/object file).

Is that possible without any compatibility problems/errors/bugs?

What else (like libraries, classes, packets) will I need to be able to design the GUI in Java?

Should these libraries be present in every computer and every OS to be able for the application to run? Or the Java Virtual Machine (JVM) installed on a computer is enough?

Comment: Use whatever UI framework you like (Swing comes "for free" with Java). Use whatever IDE you prefer (I'm a fan of IDEA products). Use the libraries that help you accomplish your tasks more easily (are we really expected to be mind-readers?). Third-party libraries can distributed (see their distribution license) and/or combined with the main JAR file. And yes, a library must be accessible *when* it is used.

Comment: Since Dec 2013 JavaFX supports Linux, Windows, MacOs, iOS, Android. Swing supports only the first three.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Swing is the framework that can help you write GUI applications in Java.
Have a look at the Swing tutorial from Oracle: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/

About platform compatibility:
Most Linux distribution installs OpenJDK (open source alternative of Java) as default Java compiler. Mostly it works fine with the program written with Oracle JDK. But if you want to be sure, you can install Oracle JDK on Linux too.

About development IDE:
Eclipse and Netbeans are both available across multiple platforms including Windows and Linux.

Answer (score 5):

1. Before bothering about nice GUI's you should get yourselfs a deeper insight into Java.
2. Java is always platform independent if you aren't using any special native libraries.
3. I recommend coding the GUI yourself. I don't even know whether there are some GUI wizards. I recommend Eclipse, but that's purely opinion based...
4. To get a cross-platform GUI which looks on every platform as a native program yould on the same, I'd recommend the Swing toolkit (`javax.swing.*`, already included into JRE/JDK)

Comment: no, java is not always platform independent --> JNI/JNA

Comment: Quote from wikipedia: "The Java Native Interface (JNI) is a programming framework that enables Java code running in a Java Virtual Machine (JVM) to call and be called by native applications (programs specific to a hardware and operating system platform) and libraries written in other languages such as C, C++ and assembly." I said: "...aren't using any special native libraries"

Answer (score 1):

Swing will do this for you.  It's not as pretty as native UI, but it works well and doesn't require any 3rd party libraries:
http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/

Answer (score 1):

You can use Eclipse IDE and for GUI you can go for either SWT or XWT

1. SWT
   http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Standard_Widget_Toolkit
2. XWT
   http://wiki.eclipse.org/XWT_Documentation

Answer (score 0):

To run a java program you need the interpreter (Java Virtual Machine) installed on the computer, that is why it's portable to any OS as long a JVM is installed.

Eclipse is a good IDE.

The GUI is too extense, but mostly AWT and Swing packages.